# Select specified div value

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="main"><div id="mainly">11</div><div id="mainly">22</div></div>
```

I want to select the div with value 11.How to do this?
I tried:

```
$("<div id="mainly">11</div>")
```

,but it didn't work...
I don't have only two divs with id="mainly".

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "select the div"?

Comment: I do it.
Something like that:
$("#mainly").each(function() {
 if($(this).text() == 11) {
  $(this).css("border","1px solid red");
 }
});

Comment: @edanfalls: what OP exactly means is "write a jquery selector to find the div"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't have only two divs with id="mainly"

But you **should** have only **one** div with the id "mainly" !

DOM identifiers have to be unique in order to create a "**well formed**" and **valid** markup.

So, we just assume you'are using `classes` instead of `ids`.

```
$('.mainly:contains(11)').fadeOut('fast');
```

Comment: +1 for actually getting to the heart of the question (`:contains`) despite the fact that ID's are being misused. mind you, contains will not look for exact matches, though, so `2112` will still match.

Comment: @David: pretty true, but OP asked for exact matches, otherwise I would have suggested a `custom selector` using regular expressions :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't have two or more div elements with the same id. This is invalid html and jQuery selectors won't work. Instead of ids use a common class for all the elements.